# Mapcache: how to calculate the x,y position of a tile?

Tags: tiles, mapcache

I use MapCache of Mapserver to generate tiles of a tif.

Given a tile (located on disk as z/y/x structure), how can I calculate it's geo-position?

Example:  `8/50/100.png` ->  `( 46.11, 11.05 )` (in wgs84)

Answer (score 1):

At end, it was simple.

1. go to your mapcache server to obtain the list of layers:

   `http://mapcacheserverurl/mapcache/tms/1.0.0/`
2. get information about layer:

   `http://mapcacheserverurl/mapcache/tms/1.0.0/LAYERNAME`
3. here you see the size of the tile in X and Y:

   `<TileFormat width="256" height="256" mime-type="image/unknown" extension="xxx"/>`

   the origin of the tiles:

   `<Origin x="43.000000" y="11.000000"/>`
4. get the units per pixel at a given zoom level:

   `<TileSet href="http://.../8" units-per-pixel="0.06" order="8"/>`
5. now, I can calculate the position of a given tile in this path:
   `8/100/86.xxx` (in my mapcache.xml configuration it's in the format z/x/y):

   `x = Origin_x + x * units-per-pixel  (43 + 100 * 0.06)`

   `y = Origin_y + y * units-per-pixel  (11 + 86 * 0.06)`